# Unable to Launch browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser, webdriver

public class LaunchBrowser {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/spectra/Drivers/geckodriver");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.seleniumhq.org");
    
    
}
```

}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type
FirefoxDriver cannot be resolved to a type

```
at com.simplilearn.day2.oops.LaunchBrowser.main(LaunchBrowser.java:16)
```

Answer (score 1):

setProperty before driver initialization which should be like

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/spectra/Drivers/geckodriver");
      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.get("https://www.seleniumhq.org");
 }
```

Comment: This should nail the OP.

Comment: so what have done is to install the latest version of selenium and latest version of driver and all errors cleared off but when i tried to run the program i got the error below:Error: Unable to initialize main class com.simplilearn.day2.oops.LaunchBrowser
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver

Comment: @oluscott Whether issue occurs even after the above changes?

Comment: what type of issues i should look out for in resolving this

Comment: @oluscott Please refer the answer

Comment: setProperty before driver initialization which should be like. public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/spectra/Drivers/geckodriver");
      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.get("https://www.seleniumhq.org"); done that still thesame errror

Comment: @oluscott Kindly post the selenium version you are using and also the type of project whether it is maven or normal java project. Check the compilation setting in eclipse if you are using it

Comment: i'm using 4.0.0-alpha-6 for Java. its just a normal java project i'm working on. Yes am using the compilation settings.      public class LaunchBrowser {

 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/spectra/eclipse-workspace/Drivers/geckodriver");
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.get("https://www.google.com");
  
  
 }
 
}